# how to add alert message in fetch request

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
In the Fetch request the need to add the alert message which should display in front end if the message response is ok status else also add alert message as error.

function LoginUser() {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,
                 'Accept': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({ "username":username, "password":password })
      
    };
     fetch('http://localhost:8080/abc', requestOptions)
     .then((response)=>{
       if(response.status==200){
          console.log('succesfull');
 }
       
         else{
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
         }
       })
       .catch((err)=>{
         console.log(err);
       });
}
```

Login

Alert message should be if response ok display successful else invalid
how to pass the alert message within the fetch request

Comment: you can use `alert` instead of `console.log` or use third-party packages such as `react-toast-notifications`

Comment: okay,  added alert message in fetch request it when response is 200 it is success fully displayed alert message on web page and console, but when it is error it is displayed in console but not displayed in web page  , is there problem in fetch request syntax of then and catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do add an alert instead of a console log.
So you can do this for the if statement.

```
if(response.status==200){
    alert('succesfull');
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).